# Raw SQL Query with Entity Framwork Core 1.1.1.0

Tags: entity-framework-core

Just trying to figure out how to execute a raw sql query with EF Core 1.1.1.0

I used to be able to create a connection and command like so:

```
var connection = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
var command = connection.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = "...";
// etc etc
```

but that doesn't seem to be available anymore. I couldn't find anything obvious in the DbContext either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can do the following:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql("YOUR QUERY HERE")
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively if you don't have a model you want to use, you should be able to do:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("YOUR QUERY HERE");
```

Sources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: The second is not an option - it does not return query. Non model queries are still not supported.

Comment: @IvanStoev How to query against dbContext? Is  `ExecuteSqlCommand` valid method in ef core?

Comment: @ManirajSS Not yet (even in latest at this time EFC 2.0). They are planning to add something, but don't know when. For now all you can do is to execute SQL queries returning entity types (like the first example in the answer).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of limitations to be aware of when using raw SQL queries:

- SQL queries can only be used to return entity types that are part of
  your model. There is an enhancement on our backlog to enable
  returning ad-hoc types from raw SQL queries.
- The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity type.
- The column names in the result set must match the column names that
  properties are mapped to. Note this is different from EF6.x where
  property/column mapping was ignored for raw SQL queries and result
  set column names had to match the property names.
- The SQL query cannot contain related data. However, in many cases you
  can compose on top of the query using the Include operator to return
  related data (see Including related data).

[**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

You can use [**Dapper**](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) liberary for complex raw sql.

Answer (score 1):

My bad. I didn't have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer installed into the project.

I'll mark JonRB's answer as correct unless this question should be taken down